# Why is the expected value of the squared value equal to the sum of the standard deviation and the mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I am currently reading the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) that one has to divide by $n-1$ in order to get an unbiased estimator of the population variance.

What I do not get is this:

\begin{equation}E[y_i^2] = \sigma^2 +\mu^2\end{equation}

I extracted that portion from the difference between line three and four of the proof. Why is it true?

Comment: I think that it is a simple rewriting of the formula 
$$\sigma^2=E((y-\mu)^2)=E(y^2)-\mu^2.$$To prove it, expand the square and note that $E(-2y\mu)=-2\mu E(y)=-2\mu^2.$

Comment: +1, nice, so easy! If you had written this as an answer, I would have accepted it :-) Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm typing my comment into an answer, please accept it so that other users will know you are satisfied with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given formula is a rewriting of the following expression for the variance (see comments above):
$$
\sigma^2 = E(y^2)-\mu^2.
$$